# Objective C how to communicate between objects?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, notifications

trying to figure out a best way of doing things.  I'm new to objective c as a language.

I have object class A, and object class B and would like A to call a method on class B and once that method is done to have B call A back tell the result.

What I'm doing now is on class A adding self to NSNotificationCenter.  Than having class B post that Notification.  It works but it seems like an overkill for this type of simple process.

Is it legal to simply pass pointer of self to class B? something like?

```
// from class A
- (void)methodInClassA
{
B * b= [[B alloc]init];
[b callMethod:self];
[b release];
b = nil;
}

where class B would be
- (void)callMethod:(A*)sender
{
    [sender resultCallbackMethod];
}
```

Comment: You should use a singleton, this would get rid of any of the issues you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW1) ([Swift 3.1](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)). [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c) is well explained.

Protocols declare methods that can be implemented by any class. Protocols are useful in at least three situations:

- To declare methods that others are expected to implement
- To declare the interface to an object while concealing its class
- To capture similarities among classes that are not hierarchically related

Comment: Thanks exactly what I needed, was looking for some type of "interface".

Comment: The protocols documentation link is broken.